# UIImage drawn in CALayer too blurry

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage, calayer

I'm having some issues getting a UIImage I draw inside a CALayer to show up without it's blurriness. I'm placing a 400x300px image into a 123x89 CALayer. The scale of this should mean that the resulting CALayer is relatively sharp, but it isn't.

This is the code I'm using to draw my UIImage:

```
    CGSize s = image.size;
    CGRect r = CGRectInset (bounds, 8, 8);
    CGFloat scale = MIN (r.size.width / s.width, r.size.height / s.height);
    s.width *= scale; s.height *= scale;
    r.origin.x += (r.size.width - s.width) * .5;
    r.size.width = s.width;
    r.origin.y += (r.size.height - s.height) * .5;
    r.size.height = s.height;

    CGContextSaveGState (ctx);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (ctx, 0, bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM (ctx, 1, -1);

    if (image != nil) {
        CGContextDrawImage (ctx, r, image.CGImage);
    }

    CGContextRestoreGState (ctx);
```

If you've ran into the same problem or know of a solution to this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Joshua Lee Tucker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just set the CALayer contents property to the CGImageRef and use the contentsGravity property to define the scaling?  You can control the size through the CALayer frame or bounds.

```
myLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
myLayer.contents = (id) [myImage CGImage];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, works perfectly. The answer resulted in much simpler code too!

Comment: I wanted to provide a reason for the fuzziness with my answer, but this really is the better solution...

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to set the contentsScale value on the CALayer or you may find the CGImage stretched outside the bounds of the view to 2 times normal size on retina devices. For some reason, the default scale on CALayers is always 1.0, even on Retina devices.

i.e.

```
layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Also, if you're drawing a shape using CAShapeLayer and wondering its edges look a little jagged on retina devices, try:

```
shapeLayer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
shapeLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Comment: last two lines helped me to fix pixelated image. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to be distorted.

First of all, the numbers don't divide into each other evenly.

Second of all, the aspect ratios of the source and destination sizes are different, so there is going to be a little bit of stretching/shrinking that way.

If you really need to do this - try to make it so the aspect ratios are the same, they can be evenly divided - or better yet - you're rendering the images to the correct destination size to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Images will tend to look fuzzy if you either place them at non-integer coordinates, or set the width/height to a non-integer value.  You are (potentially) doing both things in your code.

I think the fix for the code given would be:

```
CGFloat scale = MIN (r.size.width / s.width, r.size.height / s.height);
s.width = trunc(s.width * scale); 
s.height = trunc(s.height * scale);
r.origin.x += trunc((r.size.width - s.width) * .5);
r.size.width = s.width;
r.origin.y += trunc((r.size.height - s.height) * .5);
r.size.height = s.height;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm curious how is "fuzzy" connected with non-integer coordinates? Could you explain, please?

Comment: If coordinates are not at integer values, instead of one pixel with a single value you'll get two (or more) both with values trying to make the end result look like a single pixel of the desired value.